# How include bootstrap and jquery to vue webpack-simple template?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I need use bootstrap 3 on my vue app. I do following:

```
 vue init webpack-simple
 npm install jquery bootstrap
```

after this I add to webpack.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
 ...
   plugins: [
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
       }),
   ]
 }
```

and add to src/main.js

```
 window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
 import 'bootstrap'
```

and got error in browser:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

how I can resolve this problem?

UPDATE:

I maked like say @Sandwell, but no have bootstrap.css in result. I add line to src/main.js

```
 import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

and got webpack compilation error:

> ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   (Source code omitted for this binary file)
>    @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 6:4790-4842
>    @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
>    @ ./src/main.js
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

I have loader in webpack.config.js module.rules:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ttf)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For webpack 2

I did a vendor bundle for my libs. It should work this way.

```
  module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: 'path/to/initapp.js',
        vendor: ['jQuery', 'Bootstrap']
    }
    output: {
      path: rootPath + 'public/',
      filename: 'js/[name].js'
    }, 
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        names: ['vendor']
      })
    ]
  }
```

then jQuery should be in the vendor.js bundle
Do not forget to import it in your initapp.js

```
import 'bootstrap';
import jQuery from 'jQuery'
window.jQuery = jQuery
```

You should check this [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/) for more details

Comment: Sandwell, thanks! You respond partially help me. I Updated my question

Comment: http://hydronitrogen.com/using-bootstrap-in-a-es6-webpack-application.html did you see this post ?